# Dart - getting start - missing step - how to install pub

Tags: dart, angular-dart, dart-pub

I'm trying to get started and setup to develop Dart.
I'm following the instructions on https://webdev.dartlang.org/guides/get-started to install on Linux. However there seems to be an essential step missing.

On the above link, step 2 is about installing the SDK.
Step 3 is titled:

> Get CLI tools or WebStorm (or both)

However step gives examples of using the `pub` command, and the links it references also use this command, however there are no instructions on where to find the `pub` utility or how to install it.

I would have assumed that `pub` was provided as part of the Dart SDK. I can run `dart` in my terminal, and see that it is installed. For example `dart --version` returns `Dart VM version: 2.0.0 (Unknown timestamp) on "linux_x64"`. But `pub` returns `zsh: command not found: pub`

My question, therefore, is where do I find, and how do I install `pub`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to add the`dart-sdk/bin` directory to the system `PATH` variable.

Comment: And where would this `dart-sdk/bin` directory be located?

Comment: Depends on your OS and installer. Search your disk for the `dart.exe` in Windows or `dart` executable on other OSes. On my Debian system it's `/usr/lib/dart/bin` (contains also `pub`, `dart2js` and other executables)